# owl-date-time and http synch in angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, owl-date-time

I am using owl-date-time in my APP. I stuck with one thing,
owl-date-time  uses filter function to enable and disable days in a month, and it calls this function which is customized by me for every day in a month in sequence.

```
public  myFilter = (d: Date): boolean => {}
```

On first day of every month I need to call a server HTTP to get a list of disabled days.

```
this.disableDates = await this.http.get<any>("URL", {
    }).toPromise();
```

On first call I want to wait the HTTP return a result then allow to continue execution of the function. , which I don't know how I tried many thing didn't work.

OR anther solution if first is not possible to refresh the component and force it to call the function again after http return a result.

Any idea how to achieve first or second approach?

I am using IONIC 5  with angular 10